# WHERE + GROUP BY + HAVING to SELECT only the rows where I have different column ID's

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am trying to select only the rows where I have different columns of the PartnerID column. I have 1 simple table which contains 3 main columns - ID, Acct and PartnerID. I am trying to GROUP BY `Acct` and then check if this Acct ID have different Partners ID in it. For example if I have those rows:

```
ID    Acct    PartnerID    OperType
3     5       4            2
4     5       3            2
5     6       6            2
6     6       6            2
```

I want to be able to select the Acct with ID 5 as it contains different Partners ID's, but not selecting the Acct 6 as it has the same Partners ID.

So I tried this code, but It is not working as I am not selecting only the Acct's I need:

```
SELECT Acct
FROM `Operations`
WHERE OperType = 2
GROUP BY Acct, PartnerID
ORDER BY `Acct`  ASC
```

I also tried this, but I am geting empty result:

```
SELECT Acct
FROM `Operations`
WHERE OperType = 2
GROUP BY Acct, PartnerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PartnerID) > 1
ORDER BY `Acct`  ASC
```

Comment: @McNets, done,,

Comment: I think your GROUP BY on the second statement should be just Acct?

Comment: @JonathanFite, I think it worked now. As you suggested. I don't know it was not working before I am I sure I have tried only with Acct as well. :/

Comment: @Dimitar you can add an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jonathan Fite the answer is

```
SELECT Acct
FROM `Operations`
WHERE OperType = 2
GROUP BY Acct
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PartnerID) > 1
ORDER BY `Acct`  ASC
```